# Grammar : follow the rule

Tags: articles

Is it grammatically correct to put an "article" before "follow the rule"?

For example:

1. If the product follows the ABC design rule,......
2. If the product is made by following the ABC design rule, .....

I know the second one is correct, but if possible, I'd like to simplify the sentence as much as I can.

Comment: If “the product” is already in context, then simply: “If the ABC design rule was followed...”

Comment: Version 1 is fine.

Comment: @Jim How if there's no "The product" in context? Is the first one wrong?

Comment: *The ABC-design-rule product is*...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely correct to do so, as it refers to an existing Grammar rule and "the" is a reference back to that particular rule.

As for the word product, if you are referring to a particular product, which has already been mentioned; you may say, "the product" else "a product."

Having said that, the simple answer to your question is, an unequivocal, "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference between the two sentences: the first says the *product* follows the rule, the second says *making the product* follows the rule (suggesting that the rule is about the manufacturing process).

It's also hard to say whether "the" is correct without a specific context. For example, the manufacturing process might "follow OSHA safety rules," or it might "follow the OSHA safety rules." The first gives a sense of following OSHA's rules instead of not following any rules; the second gives a sense of selecting *OSHA's* rules, instead of a different set of rules.